# How do you change the location of the "location of configuration files" in foobar2000

Tags: user-profiles, foobar2000

Gentlepeep,

I'm aware that you can change the general "location of configuration files" under the General Option of preferences. My requirement is this:

My User Profile folder by default points to %APPDATA%\foobar2000. Would it be possible to change this through some registry setting or the likes.

I want my user profile folder to point to a customized location. Say for e.g i have a dropbox folder(i don't, i use syncplicity, but i digress..) and wish for my profile setting to get backed up through multiple PCs. I need this user profile folder of foobar2000 to lie in a place where i prefer.

Is this possible?

Many thanks
K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way to change that (indeed, the thing appears to be completely portable), but if you're on Windows Vista, or 7, you can use *symbolic links* to perform this task. I'll use the example of dropbox, because that's what I do:

1)Change the config directory to the application directory. Move the config file into your \My Dropbox folder (with foobar off)
2)Go to a command line and cd into your foobar2000 directory.
3)Run `mklink /H foobar2000.cfg "c:\path\to\your\my dropbox\folder\foobar2000.cfg"`
4)Start foobar, everything should work fine.

This works for **any file**, and `mklink /J` does the same for **any folder**. Symlinks are like shortcuts that nobody can tell are shortcuts, and combined with something like dropbox they're perfect. There IS still a file messing up your hard drive to link to it, but that's a necessary evil (and you could try `attr +s +h foobar2000.cfg` on the symlink itself, to hide it from most file views)

Comment: Thanks Mate... a great workaround. Surprised though, that something as "configurable" as foobar, doesn't have this option.
Cheers

Comment: It's weird, isn't it!